# PowerShell causes C# application to terminate on exception

Tags: c#, powershell, exception

I'm using the `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell` object to run some commands/scripts in a C# program.  The issue I'm running into is, periodically, the entire application crashes because of an exception from PowerShell which the application apparently can't catch.

Is there any way to either

1. know which command or script is executing, or
2. globally set `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` for the runspace that PS is executing in?

> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
>      at DotBuild.PowerShellCommand+d__17.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_1(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
>      at ...

Comment: *which the application apparently can't catch...* I'd be surprised if it's not possible to catch that `IOException` in your code.

Comment: You can run `$ErrorActionPreference='SilentlyContinue'` in the pipeline before executing the script but that doesn't help you if something is explicitly set to `-ErrorAction Stop`

Answer (score 0):

You may have difficulty catching the exception because it is thrown on another thread and reaches the entry point of the thread. The `QueueUserWorkItemCallback` which appears in the stack trace also points in that direction. Try handling the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event to get more information about the exception.